# xmlns : android parsing

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to parse below XML data. I need only d:MessageId and d:SerialNumber.

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" ...>
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
    <id>...</id>
    <title type="text">ViewError</title>
    <updated>2015-08-25T01:41:55Z</updated>
    <author>...</author>
    <link href="EDI_ViewError" rel="self" title="EDI_ViewError"/>
    <entry>...</entry>
    <entry>...</entry>
    <entry>
        <id>
            serveraddress
        </id>
        <title type="text">ViewError('ABCDEFG')</title>
        <updated>2015-08-25T01:41:55Z</updated>
        <category term="ViewError" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
        <link href="ViewError('GSTU7417706')" rel="edit" title="ViewError"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties   xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
                <d:MessageId>msgId_1</d:MessageId>
                <d:SerialNumber>sernr_1</d:SerialNumber>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    </feed>
```

How can I achieve this? My android code is below.

HTTP Part:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String user = "username";
String pwd = "pass";
HttpGet httpGet = new     HttpGet("properhttplink");
httpGet.addHeader("Auth Header");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

Parser Part:

```
XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
myParser.setInput(is, null);
String dee;
int event = myParser.getEventType();
while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
    String name=myParser.getName();
    switch (event){
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            if(name.equals("d")){
                dee =  myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
            }
            break;
    }
    event = myParser.next();
}
```

Please note that `myParser.getEventType()` always returns `"0"` and `myParser.getName()` always returns `"null"`.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** The name of the tag is `MessageId`, not `d`. `d` is the namespace of the tag; namespaces are used to distinguish between tags that have the same name but different meanings. If there are no other uses for `MessageId` in your document (i.e. you will never see it with any other namespace elsewhere), then you can effectively ignore it.

```
if ("MessageId".equals(parser.getName())) {
```

or, if the namespace really does matter

```
if ("d".equals(parser.getNamespace()) && "MessageId".equals(parser.getName())) {
```

**Second:** Your code uses `getAttributeValue()`, but the content you are trying to read is text content of the tag, not an attribute of the tag. You should be using `getText()` (if the current event is `TEXT`) or `nextText()` (if the current event is `START_TAG`). Which leads us to...

**Third:** You can't read the text from the `END_TAG` event.

Here's where I would start for your parser code:

```
XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser parser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(is, null);
String dee;
int event;
while ((event = parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    switch (event) {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            if ("MessageId".equals(parser.getName()) {
                dee = parser.nextText();
            }
            break;

        // TODO: other event types, if you care about them

    } // end switch
} // end while
```

Comment: while ((event = parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)

This fails in the first execution itself.

So I assume parser.next() returns 1 which is XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT

Comment: @IsmailMAC you can try running with the debugger and step through the code to see what's happening. If it's reaching `DOCUMENT_END` immediately, then you have another problem (e.g. empty XML, or you set up the parser wrong)

Comment: Thank you @karakuri...

My XML is not empty. I am just checking whats wrong with my parser

Comment: I have also added my http part, how I set the input stream.